# Can't set z-index via CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>

    <script>
        window.onload = function()
        {
            alert(document.getElementById('div1').style.zIndex);
            alert(document.getElementById('div2').style.zIndex);
        }
    </script>

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        #div2
        {
            z-index: 1;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1" style="z-index:1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
</body>
```

The outcome of the above code is "1" for the 1st alert, and nothing for the 2nd.

How come i can't set the z-index of "div2" via CSS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1: it is set, but JS cant determine it if it's not set inline
2: it would'nt have any effect, if the object is not  positioned(as gulbrandr posted)

regarding to 1. 
If it's not set inline(or by javascript), you can retrieve it using [currentStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535231%28VS.85%29.aspx) or [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3awindow.getComputedStyle) what gives you the currently applied style.

Comment: So you are saying that if i don't do it manually with javascript like: style.zIndex = 1; it will never work?

Comment: No, it also works if you set it inline `<div id="div1" style="z-index:1"></div>` , that's why you get the right value for #div1 in your example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it was the most complete. Still I don't understand why the co-op of CSS & Javascript is made like this. I mean inline style & id style should reflect the same.

Comment: I try to explain: if you access a format via ´element.style.format´ you access a attribute(style) set to the element, like any other attributes. Global stylesheets don't set/modify attributes on elements, they define rules. By that formats defined in those rules are not accessable from the element-attribute "style".

Answer (score 2):

From [W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_z-index.asp):

> z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed)

Comment: Well, even if i add position: absolute to the #div2 style, i have the same outcome.

Comment: That would explain why it didn't apply, not why it wouldn't be set.

Answer (score 1):

The `.style.*` set of properties map directly on to properties set via the `style` **attribute**, not those which are cascaded from a proper stylesheet.

To find the computed z-index, you need to use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3awindow.getComputedStyle)